# Hibernate validation does not fail on missing fields

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using `hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` in my spring boot application, however, despite the fact that my `User` class is missing the `"name"` field, hibernate validation does not alert me to the fact that the corresponding `name` column in the `user` table is not `nullable.

It is only at the point of attempting to persist a new user that the following error occurs:

> "java.sql.SQLException: Field 'name' doesn't have a default value".

Can anyone shed some light on whether or not hibernate should look for a field that is not `nullable` on the `@Entity` class?

Comment: It is more likely that you set a default value on a primary key. Primary Keys must be unique and you should use a sequence

Comment: There is no default value set, and the column not nullable:
| name         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
Yet, the field in the Entity is defined as:
private final String name;
without any annotations.
The way I understood the validation, this field declaration should fail validation against the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in your entity for non nullable columns, so it always has a default value, in other cases the value provided will saved

```
@Column(name="name")
private String name= "N/A";
```